# How to save JSON string into CSV or TXT in Python?

Tags: python, json, csv

In Python how to save the following JSON string into CSV file?

```
{
'1.txt': [], 
'2.txt': [], 
'5.txt': [], 
'4.txt': ['3.txt','6.txt'],
'7.txt': ['8.txt']
}
```

The important thing is that I want to save only numbers of those entries that have children, i.e. for the above example the result would be:

```
4
3
6
7
8
```

This is what I prepared so far, but I don't know how to check for nested elements:

```
    x = json.loads(data)

    f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "wb+"))

    # Write CSV Header
    f.writerow(["number"])

    for x in x:
            f.writerow([x[...]])
```

Comment: Your example code does not match the intended output. Your CSV declares two header fields but intended output is line-by-line. Please clarify.

Comment: @dhke: Thanks, sorry, I edited the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the list is empty or not iterating of the items in the dict:

```
for k, v in d.items(): 
    if v: # will be False for any empty list
        print(k.split(".")[0])
        print([s.split(".")[0] for s in v])
7
['8']
4
['3', '6']
```

Depending on what output you want:

```
f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w")) 

# Write CSV Header
f.writerow(["name", "qty"])


for k, v in d.items(): # iteritems python2
    if v:
        f.writerow([k.split(".")[0]]+[s.split(".")[0] for s in v])
```

Which outputs:

```
name,qty
7,8
4,3,6
```

If you want all on separate lines:

```
with open("test.csv","w") as f:
    f.write("name\n")
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v:
            f.write("{}\n".format(k.split(".")[0]))
            f.write("\n".join([s.split(".")[0] for s in v])+"\n"
```

Output:

```
name
7
8
4
3
6
```

To use the csv module you would need to wrap the subelements in lists or some container:

```
with open("test.csv","w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow(["name"])
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v:
            wr.writerow([k.split(".")[0]])
            wr.writerows([[s.split(".")[0]] for s in v])
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I just need 1 column with numbers.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos, no worries, the writerows will put on on their own line.

Comment: After running your code, I received 3 columns with some strange numbers that do not coincide with my expectations. What might be the reason?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos, you know dicts have no order yes?

Comment: For instance, first line in CSV file is "1, 8, 5", however it is not correct.

Comment: I see what happens. If I have a string "123.txt" it saves 1, 2 and 3 in new columns. How could this be fixed?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos, Using normal file.write  so probably as easy as anything, you don't have multiple columns  so there is no real need for the csv module

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham: Could you please post your example please?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos. it is the last part of the answer

Answer (score 0):

This should be working:

```
data = {
    '1.txt': [], 
    '2.txt': [], 
    '5.txt': [], 
    '4.txt': ['3.txt','6.txt'],
    '7.txt': ['8.txt']
}
f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "wb+"))
f.writerow(["name", "qty"])
for key, value in data.iteritems():
    if len(value) > 0:
        f.writerow([key, len(value)])
```

Comment: Side note: You can also use `if not value`, as `bool([]) == False`